# Add custom action to Android Share-Sheet

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

I have an app where the user should be able to share some text. Now I want to provide the default sharing options for plain text that Android provides. I do so with the following code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share");
startActivity(chooser);
```

This will look a bit like that:

[image: Share Dialog] Source: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

But now I also would like to be able to have one more option in the Share-Service-Picker Dialog that triggers a custom action in my own code. Namely I want the user to be able to favourite an entry. So beside sharing via SMS, Email, FB, whatever, I'd like there to be one more item on the top of that list, saying "Add to favourites" (Including an icon if possible).

So my question is if that's possible?!? And if, how :)

Any tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

*Intent filters inform the system what intents an application component is willing to accept. Similar to how you constructed an intent with action ACTION_SEND in the Sending Simple Data to Other Apps lesson, you create intent filters in order to be able to receive intents with this action. You define an intent filter in your manifest, using the  element. For example, if your application handles receiving text content, a single image of any type, or multiple images of any type, your manifest would look like:*

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

from [Receiving Simple Data from Other Apps:Update Your Manifest](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html)

Comment: ok, but than every app could use that action? but i'd prefer to just add an action that's only relevant to my app... I can't inflate some actions in the picker or something like that?!?